# How can I use PHP variables inside HTML tags?

Tags: php, html

I have the following doubt. I want to use php code to create a HTML form which outputs three values. And I want to use that values on a php function, something alike the following:

```
<?php
     function modcreate(){
        echo "<input type='text' name='dato'>";
        echo "<input type='text' name='nvalor'>";
        echo "<input type='text' name='identif'>";
        echo "<input type='button' onclick=mod($GET['dato'], $GET['nvalor'], 
              $GET['identif']>";
     }
?>
```

Any suggestions or cleaner ways to do this? Thank you beforehand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one

```
<?php
 function modcreate(){
    echo "<input type='text' name='dato'>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='nvalor'>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='identif'>";
    echo "<input type='button' onclick=" . mod($GET['dato'], $GET['nvalor'], 
          $GET['identif'] . ">";
 }
 ?>
```

> You were actually inserting php code inside double quotes which was behaving like a simple string. So close your double quotes before adding php tag

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to echo html in php

```
function modcreate(){ 
    ?>   
    <input type='text' name='dato'>
    <input type='text' name='nvalor'>
    <input type='text' name='identif'>
    <input type='button' onclick="mod(<?php (implode(',',[$GET['dato'],$GET['nvalor'],$GET['identif']);?>)">;
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a better syntax of how to handle html without `echo` is:

```
<?php 
function modcreate(){ ?>   
    <input  type='text' name='dato'>
    <input  type='text' name='nvalor'>
    <input  type='text' name='identif'>
    <input  type='button' 
            onclick="mod(
                <?php (implode(',',[$GET['dato'],$GET['nvalor'],$GET['identif']); ?>
            )">
<?php } ?>
```